# Label only displays %i instead of number

Tags: objective-c, string, label, chipmunk

I have a method which creates one ball each time I tap on the screen. Now, I have a label which shall show the score, for now I want to let it show how many balls there are / how many times the user tapped.

The label is called `score` and I use the following code in the method that is responsible for the tap-ball-creation.

```
scoreCount += 1;
_score.text = @"%i", scoreCount;
NSLog(@"ScoreCount = %i", scoreCount);
```

In the debugger it shows `scoreCount` increasing as it should, but the label only displays `%i` even though `scoreCount` is declared in the *.h* as `int`.

I already tried to use `%f` and `%d` instead but Xcode always tells me "Expression result unused". But why?

P.S.: I'm using chipmunk stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the second line to
_score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%i", scoreCount];